# Target Variable has Outliers : Machine Learning Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am currently working on a regression problem where the target variable has close to 2000 outliers against 54000 non outliers.

I would like to know how do we deal with data where the target variable has outliers??

Things i have tried so far:

1. Taking entire train data including outliers - score is ok ok
2. removing outliers in train data altogether - score is worse
3. taking a 80%combination of outliers in train data - score improves

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: i dont understand..isnt outlier handling done using programming??

Comment: SO is about *programming* and *coding* questions, not about *methodology* ones (such as yours); questions about ML methodology should be posted either to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or to [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As of your question, sure, as is navigation of Mars orbiters, but this doesn't mean that we will start answering questions on star navigation *here*...

Comment: thanx for the reference to other sites. and i do not agree with you..be sure to ignore questions about mars orbiter when ppl ask them.. p.s new wizard option in stackoverflow has the option to select recommendation..which is what my question was. recommendation on outlier handling.

Comment: You are very welcome to disagree; as for recommendations in general, please check point 4 in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to verify that they are explicitly off-topic for SO (not quite sure what you mean, as I don't have access to the wizard)...

Answer (score 0):

In my suggestion, If you have outliner in target variable then don't simply remove the rows from the data set instead try to bring them within the boundary limits.

You can determine the upper boundary and lower boundary but plotting box plot

```
import seaborn as sns     
sns.boxplot(x=dataset['target Variable'])
```

Also, You can count the total number of occurrences of each value in the target variable using

```
dataset['target variable'].value_counts()
```

And then set the upper bound and lower bound using the following code

```
dataset.loc[dataset['target variable'] > upper_bound, 'target variable'] = upper_limit
dataset.loc[dataset['target variable'] < Lower_bound, 'target variable'] = Lower_limit
```